# Is there an equivalent to SysInternals Autoruns for OSX?

Tags: macos, boot

I know the various directories I can look in, but I'm wondering if there is an app (or command)  that gives a single consolidated view of system and user startup items.

Optimally it would allow quickly disabling and enabling them also to troubleshoot startup problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is app with GUI also: [KnockKnock](https://objective-see.com/products/knockknock.html)

> "Who's there?" See what's persistently installed on your Mac.

Answer (score 3):

There's [OSX Autoruns](http://www.malicious-streams.com/Downloads/files/6bad73d5437c84b23fde9ebad97c7cff-6.html):

> OSX Autoruns is a Python-based, Mac OS X utility that displays items set to auto-launch at either system boot or user login. The majority of auto-launch items on Mac OS X comes from a series of Property List (plist) files. OSX Autoruns.py extracts startup information from the various relevant plist files and displays them in a variety of output formats.

I guess someone could always create a GUI front-end for this.

Comment: It's a good start, nowhere as powerful as AutoRuns though. Thanks!